# Histograma em Java

Tags: java, array, histograma

Olá,

Necessito transformar uma imagem em uma matriz de pixels.

Por exemplo: Dada a imagem "netuno.jpeg", de 256 x 256 pixels, preciso alocar o valor dos pixels nessa Matriz e imprimir a quantidade que esses pixel aparecem em outro vetor:

Matriz[0][0] = 2 (sendo 2 o valor do pixel),

Matriz[0][1] = 12, ... , Matriz[255][255] = 23

Qtd de pixels 0 = 34 (sendo 34 a quantide de vezes em que o pixel de valor 0 apareceu) ,

Qtd de pixels 1 = 21, ... , Qtd de pixels 255 = 120

Até agora eu li a imagem usando BufferedImage, mas não sei como acessar os pixels da imagem.

```
import xxx;

public class Histograma {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //Atributos

    //Métodos

    //Leitura da Imagem - Planeta Netuno

    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/patch/netuno.jpeg"));
    int altura = img.getHeight();
    int largura = img.getWidth();
    int[][] matrix = new int[largura][altura];

    for(int i = 0; i < img.getWidth(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < img.getHeight(); j++) {

        }
    }           
}
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Lendo a documentação da classe [BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), me parece que você pode ler o valor RGB de cada pixel na posição (x, y), valor este que é retornado como um `int`. O nome do método é `getRGB(int x, int y)`. Obtido o valor RGB, pode-se quebrá-lo nos componentes vermelho, verde e azul aplicando um pouco de escovação de bits, se isso for necessário. Ou apenas use como índice para seu histograma.